# How can I save the video to MediaStore by CameraX on Java?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, video, camera

I saw [this page](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/video-capture#configure-and-create-recording) to learn how to take some video captures and save them to a device.

the Android official code:

```
// Create MediaStoreOutputOptions for our recorder
val name = "CameraX-recording-" +
        SimpleDateFormat(FILENAME_FORMAT, Locale.US)
                .format(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".mp4"
val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
   put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, name)
}
val mediaStoreOutput = MediaStoreOutputOptions.Builder(this.contentResolver,
                              MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
                              .setContentValues(contentValues)
                              .build()

// 2. Configure Recorder and Start recording to the mediaStoreOutput.
val recording = videoCapture.output
                .prepareRecording(context, mediaStoreOutput)
                .withAudioEnabled()
                .start(ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this), captureListener)
```

but I am using Java and I can’t find the `output` member on Java(if this is a Kotlin keyword, can you tell me what it means?).

I want to save the video that was captured by `CameraX` but my project is not using Kotlin.

Can somebody translate it to java for me?

thanks!!

Comment: Hi, can you please share its java code, specifically code for the captureListener in Java? And please help me that how to get recorded video?

Comment: I am sorry that I finished this project, you can check the type to find some hints, good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different `VideoCapture` classes.

One is in `"androidx.camera:camera-core:$version"` imported as `androidx.camera.core.VideoCapture`.

The other one is in `"androidx.camera:camera-video:$version"` imported as `androidx.camera.video.VideoCapture`.

Only the second one has the methods you need. And since you are using Java you have to replace `output` with `getOutput()`.